# Does anyone know of this manifestation of the Littlewood-Richardson coefficients for the complete flag variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, schubert-calculus

This is the culmination of about 11 years of research but after I discovered it I found a proof that was extremely trivial, so I'm wondering if it's already known.

Let $(a,b)$ with $a < b$ positive integers denote the transpositions in the symmetric group. Turn them into a vector space with the relation
$$(a,b)+(b,c)=(a,c)$$
(This is the root system thinly disguised.) Let $F$ be the tensor algebra on this vector space. For an element $w\in S_{\infty}$ define
$$T_w = \sum_{\substack{(a_1,b_1)\cdots (a_n,b_n) = w\\\ell((a_1,b_1)\cdots (a_i,b_i))=i}} (a_1,b_1)\cdots (a_n,b_n)$$
Then the elements $T_w$ are linearly independent. Define
$$T_{w/u} = \sum_{\substack{u(a_1,b_1)\cdots (a_m,b_m) = w\\\ell(u(a_1,b_1)\cdots (a_i,b_i))=\ell(u)+i}} (a_1,b_1)\cdots (a_m,b_m)$$
Then
$$T_{w/u}=\sum_{v}{c_{u,v}^wT_v}$$
where $c_{u,v}^w$ is the structure constant in the cohomology ring of the complete flag variety.

So the question is: is this already known?

Comment: Looks like the "Monk's/Chevalley's rule" way of defining Schubert polynomials...

Comment: @Sam Do you have a reference? I'm aware these are dual to Schubert polynomials in a nice way, and you can get a formula for Schubert polynomials in terms of the degree 1 Schubert polynomials by inverting their coefficient matrix.

Comment: In general that there are two approaches to defining Schubert polynomials: a "top-down" approach where you start by defining $\mathfrak{S}_{w_0} = x_1^{n-1}x_2^{n-2}\cdots x_{n-1}$ and use divided difference operators to get smaller $w$'s from bigger ones going down along edges of the weak order; and a "bottom-up" approach where you start by defining $\mathfrak{S}_{\mathrm{id}}=1$ and use Monk's rule (or maybe more precisely Lascoux's transition formula, see Theorem 3.4 of http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~allenk/schubnotes.pdf) to get bigger $w$'s from smaller along edges of the strong order.

Comment: You are summing over paths from the identity to $w$ in the strong order, so it looks like the bottom-up approach to me. But can't say more precisely than that.

Comment: @Sam Thanks. This formula actually comes from the coproduct for divided difference operators from my dissertation, by like I said I also found a trivial proof. The main thing I'm asking about is the identity for $T_{w/u}$.

Comment: Your result could be the same as Theorem 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0202090.pdf.

Comment: @Richard I see what you mean. It is very closely related, and I need to look at this a bit harder. There may be a transformation from one formula to the other. Thanks.